# Apache Spark DataFrame apply custom operation after GroupBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 columns say `ID, value` Id is of type `Int` and value is of type `List[String]`.

Ids are repeating so to make them unique I apply `GroupBy("id")` on My DataFrame now my problem is I want to append the value with each other and value column must be distinct.

Example :- i have a data like

```
+---+---+
| id| v |
+---+---+
|  1|[a]|
|  1|[b]|
|  1|[a]|
|  2|[e]|
|  2|[b]|
+---+---+
```

and i want my output like this

```
+---+---+--
| id| v   |
+---+-----+
|  1|[a,b]|
|  2|[e,b]|
```

i tried this :-

> val uniqueDF = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("v")) 
>   uniqueDf.map{row => (row.getInt(0),
>   row.getAsSeq[String].toList.distinct)}

Can I do the same after `groupBy()` say in `agg()` or something I do not want to apply map operation

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val uniqueDF = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set("v"))`

Set will have only unique values

Comment: this is correct but i also want to perform some custom operation like filter and all can i do that too.

Comment: you will get same output that you get after your map stage... so further will remain the same